# Python ElementTree XMLWriter strange behaviour at end of file

Tags: python, elementtree, xmlwriter

here is the code I am using to dynamically build an XML file from a MonoDB query:

```
w = XMLWriter(filename,'utf-8')
schedule = w.start('Schedule')
for p in placements:
    ep = db.episodes.find_one({'HouseID':p['HouseID']})
    if ep:
        w.start('Row')
        w.element('Time','%s' % p['Start'].strftime('%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p'))
        w.element('ProgID','%s' % ep['Program']['Pili_ID'])
        w.element('HouseID','%s' % p['HouseID'])
        w.end()
w.close(schedule)
```

A strange thing is happening at the end of the XML file.  I can't figure out where `<Tim/>` is coming from.  Incidentaly, I have ommited the thousands of correct rows that appear between the start and the end:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Schedule>
  <Row>
    <Time>01/12/2011 12:30:00 PM</Time>
    <ProgID>5077</ProgID>
    <HouseID>AU056563</HouseID>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <Time>05/12/2011 12:00:00 AM</Time>
    <ProgID>5077</ProgID>
    <HouseID>AU056563</HouseID>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <Tim/>
  </Row>
</Schedule>
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe </Tim> its a misspelled <Time> ?

Comment: That's what I thought but can you see the error anywhere in my code? I can't. The module is generating Tim. Why??

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it makes a difference, but shouldn't there be an additional `w.end()` (for the Schedule element) before `w.close()`?
I can see that in the output the Schedule element is closed, but I also see the aberrant behaviour.